# the disjoint union of complete graphs is ds, with respect to adjacency matrix.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, spectral-graph-theory

In [Which graphs are determined by their spectrum?](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S002437950300483X) proposition 6 states "the disjoint union of complete graphs is DS, with respect to adjacency matrix." A graph is said to be DS (determined by its spectrum) if its spectrum uniquely determines its isomorphism class.
I read the proof and I was confused.

I searched about it. I found this: [On NP-hard graph properties characterized by the spectrum](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X20303401). In lemma 1, there is the same result. To prove the lemma, it's stated: "... a graph $G$ (with at least one edge) is the disjoint union of cliques if and only if $G$ has smallest eigenvalue $−1$. But we can say more. If the smallest eigenvalue is $−1$, then every other eigenvalue $\lambda$ is a nonnegative integer, and corresponds to a clique of order $\lambda+1$." It seems it's easier but I can't prove it.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A graph is the disjoint union of cliques if and only if the graph does not contain a $3$-vertex path as an induced subgraph: if, whenever $uv \in E$ and $vw \in E$, we also have $uw \in E$.

Induced subgraph characterizations help us understand eigenvalues (and vice versa) because of the eigenvalue interlacing theorem. This says that if $A$ is a symmetric matrix (like, say, a graph's adjacency matrix) with eigenvalues $\alpha_1 \le \dots \le \alpha_n$, and $B$ is a principal submatrix of $A$ (like, say, the adjacency matrix of an induced subgraph) with eigenvalues $\beta_1 \le \dots \le \beta_k$, then
$$
    \alpha_i \le \beta_i  \qquad\text{and}\qquad \beta_{k+1-i} \le \alpha_{n+1-i}
$$
for $i=1, \dots, k$. (The $i^{\text{th}}$ smallest eigenvalue of $A$ is smaller than the $i^{\text{th}}$ smallest eigenvalue of $B$, and the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest eigenvalue of $A$ is larger than the $i^{\text{th}}$ largest eigenvalue of $B$.)

In our case, the $3$-vertex path $P_3$ has eigenvalues $-\sqrt2 \le 0 \le \sqrt2$. Therefore if a graph has a $3$-vertex path as an induced subgraph, its smallest eigenvalue is $-\sqrt2$ or less. The *only* graphs that can have a smallest eigenvalue of $-1$ are disjoint unions of cliques. (We haven't proven that they have this property yet - just that nothing else can.)

The eigenvalues of $K_n$ are $n-1$ (with multiplicity $1$) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $n-1$). When we take disjoint unions, we just combine all the eigenvalues. Therefore, the eigenvalues of $K_{n_1} \cup \dots \cup K_{n_t}$ are $n_1-1, \dots, n_t -1$ (with multiplicity $1$) and $-1$ (with multiplicity $n_1 + \dots + n_t - t$).

If $n_1 = \dots = n_t = 1$, we have the empty graph, whose eigenvalues are all $0$. Otherwise, this graph does indeed have a smallest eigenvalue of $-1$, possibly with very large multiplicity.

Comment: I'm not sure I understood correctly. But what I found is that we assume that $G$ is cospectral with disjoint union of cliques. If $G$ has $P_3$ as an induced subgraph, then by interlacing theorem, we have the smallest eigenvalue of $G$ must be lesser than $-\sqrt{2}$, a contradiction. So, it doesn't have $P_3$ as an induced subgraph. Thus $G$ isomorphic with disjoint union of cliques. Is it correct?

Comment: The part you described about matrix and  eigenvalues, is another version of interlacing Theorem? I has seen this version: Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and $H$ be an induced subgraph of order $m$,with these eigenvalues: $\lambda_n(G)\leq\cdots \leq \lambda_2(G) \leq \lambda_1(G)$
 and
 $\lambda_m(H)\leq\cdots \leq \lambda_2(H) \leq \lambda_1(H)$. Then for every $1\leq i\leq m$, we have: $$\lambda_{n-m+i}(G)\leq\lambda_i(H)\leq\lambda_i(G).$$

Comment: In first comment, we found  $G$ is isomorphic to the disjoint union of cliques. How do we determine the cliques are exactly those we have? I think we can do it by the positive eigenvalues, is it correct? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Dear Misha, can you help me for this question?https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4226510/spectrum-of-a-regular-graph-and-its-girth?noredirect=1#comment8778073_4226510

Comment: Yes, yes, yes, and maybe.